# How to configure database service status with Zabbix by simple check agent-less

Tags: postgresql, tcp, monitoring, zabbix

I have to configure a simple check for PostgreSQL database service with Zabbix without Agent installed on machine.

I thought to use simple check TCP by *net.tcp.service[service,ip,port]*.

The simple check return:

- **0** if service is down
- **1** if service is running

What and where can I configure the chek into Zabbix Server?

reference at : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks

Must I configure the trigger on the host or Application and the Web scenario ?

Comment: i think this question is more  suitabe for https://serverfault.com/ ( question and answer site for system and network administrators )

Comment: And this seems like a too generic "tell me what to do" question. What have you tried and what did not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a simple check as a item on the Zabbix server host, like `net.tcp.service[tcp,192.168.1.1,5432]` and its corresponding trigger through the web interface.

A better approach could be through ODBC checks or with a simple script which calls a `SELECT ....` to capture more details about the service.

The best approach is the Zabbix Agent: log monitoring, process monitoring etc..

Regarding your last question: Host, Application and Web Scenarios are different things. I strongly suggest you to start [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/quickstart)

Comment: I'm in the context agentless, it works. I just created on my host an item with net.tcp.service[tcp,host+domain,5432] and the trigger associated to item with the followed expression {host:net.tcp.service[tcp,host+domain,5432].last()}<>1